# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9 - Failed to resolve packages

Tags: android

I'm getting several errors within Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9.  These errors are "Failed to resolve:" the android packages, some listed below. 
 I just installed all the extra packages for the SDK and I'm still getting a gradle build error:

```
Error:(82, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2
Error:(85, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0
Error:(89, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0
Error:(97, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0
```

and a few more packages relating to testing and the support libraries.

Here is my build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha9'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
    }
}
```

I'm really not sure why this is failing to build.  I just updated all the packages and all the support libraries are the same at the 26.0.0 --> `compileSdkVersion 26`

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

[EDIT] - Here is my gradle build log

```
Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.2/multidex-1.0.2.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v13/26.0.0/support-v13-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/mediarouter-v7/26.0.0/mediarouter-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:design:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.0/design-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/26.0.0/recyclerview-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.0/appcompat-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0
> Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/cardview-v7/26.0.0/cardview-v7-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0
> Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Users/bcalabro/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      file:/Applications/Android Studio 3.0 Preview.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.4
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Writing:

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

didn't worked in my case, so I used:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

and it worked!

checkout the [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html) for more info!

Comment: the solution you posted did not work for me.  I simply am unable to use the support packages for 26.0.0, I have kept them at 25.3.1 for the time being!  I'm really not sure why they aren't loading!

Comment: btw, you can load those packages(26.0.0) using android studio 2.3.3 as well, since 3.0 is still in canary!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/migration.html

check the "Update your build configuration" section

Comment: it looks like I needed to use the `26.0.0-beta2` versions, `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'` as an example

Comment: @Brandon according to me, they just didn't updated the doc to the latest version of support library. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: @SarthakMittal You're solution is worked for me. Thanks