# Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

After migrating from Android Studio 3.0 (Canary 5) to Android Studio 3.0 (Beta 1), and moving to latest gradle , i.e. `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'`

When I try to gradle sync, it error stating below.

```
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2
```

I check on [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 9 - Failed to resolve packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486553/android-studio-3-0-canary-9-failed-to-resolve-packages), it doesn't solve my problem, as I already have this

```
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
```

I'm surprise it is even asking for multidex 1.0.2, as I only have in my build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

I check using `./gradlew app:dependencies | grep multidex`, it shows the failures as below (across various flavors etc)

```
+--- com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2 FAILED
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 FAILED
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1 -> 1.0.2 FAILED
```

Where did the dependencies of `multidex:1.0.2` and `multidex-instrumentation:1.0.2` comes from? How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Where you added `url 'https://maven.google.com'` ?

Comment: in my project wide `build.gradle` scope within `repositories` together with other mavens

Comment: Did you update support repository and all other required stuff ?

Comment: You're right, I put my maven in the `buildscript` `repositories`, instead of `allprojects` `repositories` . Thanks!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Apparently my issue is I should post this:

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

in `allprojects` and not in `buildscript` (the subtle different has blinded me where the issue is), which then looks like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to M D for the pointers!

Comment: Yep! Go to root build.gralde and make sure to add google() to allProjects {} and not buildscript {}. Just had the same issue.

Comment: @Elye Useful for user who has updated Android Studio with latest version

Comment: it also works if instead of "url 'http.... " you use simply:  "google()"

Comment: still having the issue. this solution is not working for me.

Comment: In addition to you solution had to add this    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Answer (score 23):

For me, the solution is move the **google()** item up to make sure it's before the **jcenter()**. And actually, I will put the **google()** in the first place of all the repositories.

Comment: It seems something changed from jcenter about 3 days ago and broke our automated build system with this exact error(with no code change on our end in the interim). I would guess jcenter was declaring it had the lib and then returning 404 or something. Flipping the order worked, so have an upvote :-)

Answer (score 10):

Need to add the following as well:

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

After adding the above line, it worked for me in addition to the above answer

Comment: How to implement this solution in Phonegap Build ?

Comment: please add the above line in your module build file.

Comment: but Phonegap doesn't provide any option to edit the build file ? Am right I guess ?

Comment: can you let me know the solution

Answer (score 6):

First you need to clean the project  , and then rebuild it.

Build ----> Clean Project

Build ----> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 6):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

worked for me instead of

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are in China,
Please use

```
allprojects {
    respositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

to instead

```
allprojects {
    respositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}
```

don't ask me why, I don't want to tell you.... may be 'https://maven.google.com' was selected by GFW?

Answer (score 3):

Adding google() in my allprojects solved my issue...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If none of the above solutions are working then add `mavenLocal()` :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
               maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }

        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I did it to load the maven from my local repository and it worked. So, I specified that if none other work then give a hit to it as well.

Answer (score 2):

Move the **google()** item up to make sure it's before the **jcenter()**.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

Comment: Wow! Wish I had stumbled up this before spending an hour racking my head trying to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update all the gradle dependencies to latest version ..
That’s it

Answer (score 0):

my problem was network connection. I needed to connect to a vpn server to connect to jcenter

Answer (score 0):

In my cases, I have no need to requires **multidex** but I have added due to other dependencies requires[brightcove player]

So I have added below lines in ***gradle.properties*** and error was gone.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
anpVersion=6.18.3
```